# How to insert lightning component to visualforce page with apex after button click

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning

I want to insert a lightning component to a visualforce page after a button click is done in the visualforce page. So I want to do some vf-controller functions and then open a lightning component in the apex controller of the vf page.

Answer (score 0):

After button click use at function but you need to create one app for it

```
<div id="lightning" />

<script>
    $Lightning.use("c:Test", function() {
      $Lightning.createComponent("c:testCMP",
      "lightning",
      function(cmp) {
        // do some stuff
      });
    });
</script>
```

You need to create one lighting app and add dependency in it

c:Test is App and c:testCMP is component